# Futur I oder Präsens mit Zeitangaben - welches Tempus wird häufiger von Muttersprachlern verwendet?

Tags: grammar-identification

Ich habe im Forum die Antwort auf meine Frage - ehrlich - für eine gute Weile nachgesucht, leider ohne ein für mich befriedigendes Ergebnis...

Ich frage mich, ob Muttersprachler in alltäglicher Kommunikation eher Präsens (mit Zeitangaben) oder Futur I verwenden. Die grammatischen Regeln sind mir selbstverständlich schon bekannt, aber...

Da ich in meiner beruflichen Praxis (Steuerberatung) meist mit deutschen Unternehmen zu tun habe, interessiere ich mich besonders, wie man beispielweise die Informationen über die kommenden Gesetzesänderungen oder geplanten Geschäftvorfälle dem Kunden am besten mitteilen sollte. Aufgrund meiner Herkunft (Polnisch) beobachte ich, die Tendenz es mit Verwendung des Futur I zu formulieren.

*Beispiel*:

> Die neuen Vorschriften treten am 1. November 2019 in Kraft.

oder

> Die neuen Vorschriften werden am 1. November 2019 in Kraft treten.

Ich mache mir Gedanken, ob es vielleicht auf der anderen Seite keine Verwirrung verursachen könnte, wenn man Futur I benutzt.

Comment: Beachte dabei aber auch unterschiedlichen Verb Aspekte. "to meet [a target]" ist eines der Beispiele für Verbs of Achievement, die kein Imperfekt kennen. "in Kraft treten" ist m.M.n. ähnlich.

Comment: Es kommt nicht zuletzt darauf an, ob man mündlich oder schriftlich kommuniziert, und wie locker oder formal die Kommunikationssituation ist.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn etwas konkret (oder mit ziemlicher Sicherheit) feststeht, zum Beispiel das Datum, an dem die neuen Vorschriften in Kraft treten, so wird im Allgemeinem das Präsens genutzt:

> Die neuen Vorschriften treten am 1. November 2019 in Kraft.
>   [Nächstes Jahr|Morgen|In einer Woche] treten die neuen Vorschriften in Kraft.

Wenn noch nicht so klar ist, wann das passieren wird, nutzt man das Futur I:

> Die neuen Vorschriften werden definitiv in Kraft treten, wann ist allerdings noch unklar.

Siehe auch hier: https://easy-deutsch.de/zeitformen/futur-1/#tab-con-4

Answer (score 1):

In der gesprochenen Sprache wird fast immer das Präsens verwendet (mit einer Zeitangabe):

> Was machst du Sonntag Abend? Gehen wir ins Kino?
>
> - Ich habe keine Zeit, ich schaue dann "Tatort".

Das wird zum Beispiel auch in der deutschen Wikipedia beschrieben: [futurisches Präsens](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4sens#Zum_futurischen_Pr%C3%A4sens).